# Serializer Import Error on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to get started with the Django REST Framework by following the tutorial at the following link:
**http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/**

However, in following the directions here I'm running into an error once I start my server that goes as follows:

> `Could not import 'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer' for API setting 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES'. ImportError: cannot import name serializers.`

It somehow feels like a compatibility issue so I looked up my package versions and came up with the following:

- Django==1.7.7
- djangorestframework==3.1.1
- Python==2.7.6

I was wondering if anyone might have any ideas on what the issue might be.  Apologies if I didn't provide enough information, happy to provide more, just not sure exactly what's relevant at this point.

Thanks!

-- UPDATE

Thanks Kevin, adding the output from the command you linked below:

```
In [1]: from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-92bc65a288f2> in <module>()
----> 1 from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py in <module>()
     18 from django.test.client import encode_multipart
     19 from django.utils import six
---> 20 from rest_framework import exceptions, serializers, status, VERSION
     21 from rest_framework.compat import SHORT_SEPARATORS, LONG_SEPARATORS, INDENT_SEPARATORS
     22 from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError

C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py in <module>()
     40 # serializer fields more explicit.
     41
---> 42 from rest_framework.relations import *  # NOQA
     43 from rest_framework.fields import *  # NOQA
     44

C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py in <module>()
      9 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
     10 from rest_framework.compat import OrderedDict
---> 11 from rest_framework.fields import get_attribute, empty, Field
     12 from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
     13 from rest_framework.utils import html

C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py in <module>()
----> 1 from rest_framework import serializers
      2
      3 from .models import User, Post, Photo
      4
      5

ImportError: cannot import name serializers

In [2]:
```

Comment: Open up a shell and do `python -c 'from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer'` (replicating the bad import) and add any tracebacks to your question.

Comment: are u using a virtualenv?

Comment: hey levi, I am not. Just doing things right on my local machine. Perhaps I should give the old delete all and reinstall a try...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, for me upgrade the django rest solved the problem! I used this command

```
pip install djangorestframework --upgrade
```